# Como cambiar el valor del "Title" en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Alguien ha modificado el valor del **title** en **WPF**, quiero lograr mostrar un valor en este espacio.

```
Title="text" + key
```

Este es el que tengo actualmente, quisiera poder concatenarlos con otra variable que tengo en una **[key] del App.config**

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta de SO en ingles. [How to use a App.config file in WPF applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/806174).

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa No es lo que necesito, pero igual muchas gracias. la idea es poder concatenar el valor de la key en ese espacio de title de la ventana de Wpf. De nuevo mil gracias

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Donde quieres modificarlo? En el Xaml? En el codebehind? Usas MVVM y esa es tu duda? Pq si es en el codebehind, `this.Title="texto"` y ya está...

Comment: Listo, entonces el key ya lo obtienes, es que en tu pregunta se entiende que tienes el valor en el app.config y necesitas obtenerlo para concatenar. Especifica en tu pregunta que el valor ya lo obtienes.

Comment: @Pikoh Perfecto me funciono! mil gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se usa desde el codebehind

```
public Principal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = "..."; //Aquí va el texto que quieres en la ventana
        }
```

Y desde el **XAML** quitas la etiqueta **Title**

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder al App.Config tienes que usar el objeto Settings, en tu caso debes hacer lo siguiente:

Primero ve al menú **PROYECTO** de Visual Studio -> **Propiedades de (tu proyecto)**, luego cuando entras vas a **Configuración** y ahí añades las claves que quieres tener disponibles en tu App.Config, recomiendo a nivel usuario.

El App.Config quedaría algo asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="TuProyecto.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
      <OpenForiver.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ClaveQueQuieroUsar" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </OpenForiver.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Y en el código lo llamas así:

```
this.Title = "text" + Settings.Default["ClaveQueQuieroUsar"];
```

Y listo, con eso queda.